# Phonegap captureImage does nothing

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins, cordova-2.0.0

I've built my first iOS app and everything works but snapping photos. 
Below is my Phonegap config file and further down the JavaScript part that according to my understanding of the manual should let the user snap a photo.

When I call `navigator.device.capture.captureImage` nothing happens.

What am I missing?

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<widget xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:gap="http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0" id="dk.webcom.longhaul" version="1.0.0">

    <preference name="AllowInlineMediaPlayback" value="false" />
    <preference name="AutoHideSplashScreen" value="true" />
    <preference name="BackupWebStorage" value="cloud" />
    <preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="false" />
    <preference name="EnableLocation" value="false" /><!-- DEPRECATED -->
    <preference name="EnableViewportScale" value="false" />
    <preference name="FadeSplashScreen" value="true" />
    <preference name="FadeSplashScreenDuration" value=".25" />
    <preference name="HideKeyboardFormAccessoryBar" value="false" />
    <preference name="KeyboardDisplayRequiresUserAction" value="true" />
    <preference name="KeyboardShrinksView" value="false" />
    <preference name="MediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction" value="false" />
    <preference name="ShowSplashScreenSpinner" value="true" />
    <preference name="SuppressesIncrementalRendering" value="false" />
    <preference name="TopActivityIndicator" value="gray" />

    <content src="index.html" />

    <plugins>
        <plugin name="Device" value="CDVDevice" />
        <plugin name="Logger" value="CDVLogger" />
        <!--<plugin name="Compass" value="CDVLocation" />-->
        <!--<plugin name="Accelerometer" value="CDVAccelerometer" />-->
        <plugin name="Camera" value="CDVCamera" />
        <plugin name="NetworkStatus" value="CDVConnection" />
        <!--<plugin name="Contacts" value="CDVContacts" />-->
        <!--<plugin name="Echo" value="CDVEcho" />-->
        <plugin name="File" value="CDVFile" />
        <plugin name="FileTransfer" value="CDVFileTransfer" />
        <plugin name="Geolocation" value="CDVLocation" />
        <plugin name="Notification" value="CDVNotification" />
        <!--<plugin name="Media" value="CDVSound" />-->
        <plugin name="Capture" value="CDVCapture" />
        <!--<plugin name="SplashScreen" value="CDVSplashScreen" />-->
        <!--<plugin name="Battery" value="CDVBattery" />-->
        <!--<plugin name="Globalization" value="CDVGlobalization" />-->
        <!--<plugin name="InAppBrowser" value="CDVInAppBrowser" />-->
    </plugins>

    <access origin="*" />

</widget>
```

Here is the JavaScript part that should open the camera.

```js
        navigator.device.capture.captureImage @photoSuccess, @photoFail,
            limit: 1
        # navigator.camera.getPicture app.photoSuccess, app.photoFail,
        #   quality: 50
        #   destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems I was missing `<script src="cordova-2.7.0.js"></script>` in index.html